# Wpf round button with high contrast

Tags: wpf, windows, high-contrast

```
<Button Name="captureImageBtn" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="71" Height="70" Click="captureImageBtn_Click" BorderBrush="#e8f4ff" BorderThickness="2">
    <Button.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Border">
            <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="35"/>
        </Style>
    </Button.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <Image Name="imageImg" Source="\Resources\light-icon-camera.png" Height="24"> </Image>
        <TextBlock Margin="0, 5, 0, 0" Text="{x:Static local:Resources.Toolbar_Image}"></TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

Using the code above, I have a round button with an image above the title.

Switching to a High contrast theme on windows 11, the buttons become square.
How do I get round buttons with High contrast enabled?

Comment: If you target the button in the style and use `Border.CornerRadius` as the property does that work?

Comment: Button does not have CornerRadius i think.

Comment: Not directly but you can access it via `Border.CornerRadius` if I remember correctly

Comment: Isn't the code above already setting the CornerRadius on the border?